# Is it possible to creare a counting function for html pages?

Tags: html

I am making a quiz with several html pages (question1, question2, etc) each one with 4 options with radio buttons so only one can be checked. What I would like to have is a function that, if you selected the right answer, adds 1 point to a counter, but if you checked a wrong answer, takes away 0.25 points. In the end, I would have a page with the final grade of the quiz, that would be the sum of the points for each question. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Going to need to use JavaScript

Comment: You don't need several HTML pages for that, you can do everything on one page.

Comment: If you will use JavaScript

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutriedsofar.com/)

Comment: Well I am new to all of this, but I know I need to use JavaScript, the problem is that I have only been working with this for 5 days and my knowledge is not very extense. The problem is I don't know how to make a function that works in different pages to keep the count and finally show the grade.

Comment: Guys, do you even consider some sort of security when you suggesting to do such things client side? Such things should be done server side if you want results of that quiz really mean something. With all that said I have two questions: 1) are you OK with users faking results using browser debugging tools and if "No" 2) what is the server side technology do you use?

Comment: Oh, no, it is not even going to be on the Internet, it is just a college project, they make us do a little 10 question quiz with 4 answers and only one correct. We have to have 10 html pages each one with a question and then a final page that shows the results of the quiz. I have been searching about javascript or php but for the moment I don't seem to find any good solution

Comment: Even small college projects should be done right. If you'll make a behavior of do not caring for security you will not care about it even on a big projects. There will be no better time to learn about such thing than now. Funny enough though, this reminded me when I was a 1st year student in University in early 2000s and somebody of my teachers put together testing system fully client side. During the test I found it out and demonstrated how easy to "hack" it to my professor. When they didn't do anything about it for a week I "leaked" this info to every person I knew.

Comment: Good one mate, did they find out? Do you know a way to keep count of the checked radio buttons from 10 pages to sum the results and display them on screen?

Comment: Of course the did, b/c I was the only person who was bugging them about it the whole week. However, after that they offered me position on very interesting project :) Anyway, for your case when user answered a question I would post question answer to the server, on the server side figure out if response is correct and store it in server variable that never get sent to the client. On your summary page you could display the score that is getting calculated using that variable.

Comment: Great, thank you very much mate! I'm going to try it and see what happens! 
How cool is that? You hack them and even get a position in a project! Not often happens like this lol!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript or PHP to make a variable and add or minus the variable each page. Then show it on the final page. Most of the HTML book cover this topic, try to borrow some books about JavaScript, since HTML is not a dynamic language.

You can just use POST method or GET method in both php and JavaScript to send the number to next page.

W3school.com provide free and detail tutorial about HTML php JavaScript and many more language.

Comment: What I don't understand is how I create a single function that works for 10 different html pages, where do I put the function? How do I count the good or bad results? Sorry mate, I am just too new in this subject...